A change of variables in limits leading to a false result
In the following example, we have $ \lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x) $ .
Why am I not permitted to take the change of variable $x= y+\pi$?
I understand that if I wish to change variables in a limit the old variable should be equal to a continuous function of the new variable i.e.: $x=f(y)$ such that $f(y)$ is a continuous function whose range is in the domain of definition of this instance $\sin(x)$.
If I do take $x=y+\pi$ then i get $\lim_{(y+\pi) \to\infty }\sin(y+\pi)=\lim_{y\to\infty} -\sin(y)= - \lim_{y\to\infty}\sin(y)$.
But $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ = $\lim_{y\to\infty}\sin(y)$
then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x) = -\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ so
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)=0$ which is false .
Can anyone help me solve this please?
the limit should be undefined as $\sin$ alternates between $-1$ and $1$. is this sufficient to prove the limit is undefined?
thank you

if someone can show me other examples of similar cases where one can see what the mistake is, where taking a change of variables is not allowed  or point me to a relevant text to help me understand i would be very grateful. thank you ever so much

You may manipulate limits like that only if the limits exists.

@jjagmath but how would one know if the limit exists before one tries to solve it and manipulate it? should i use a test to see if the limit exists first then try to see what the limit is. thank you for your help

You don't know. That's usual when manipulating limits. One uses equalities between limits assuming that the limits exists. For example, when one writes $\lim (f+g) = \lim f + \lim g$, one is applying the theorem whose complete form reads:  "If $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exists, then $\lim (f+g)$ exists and equals $\lim f + \lim g$. But you don't usually write all that.

@jjagmath i see this was really helpful to clear some confusions i had. thank you ever so much. appreciate the help :)

This limit does not exist, in fact, the idea is that depending on the way you approach $\infty$, the sine approaches different values, for example: consider the sequence of points $y_n = \dfrac{\pi}{2}(2n+1).$ if $n$ is even $\sin(y_n) = 1$ and if $n$ is odd $\sin (y_n)=-1$. Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ you observe that the limit does not converge to a single value. In particular the problem is that the limit does not exist so you cannot apply properties like the limit of sum or multiplication, like $0 . \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \sin(y) \neq 0$.

ahh i see so the way you approach a limit from both sides should be uniform and lead to the same result, but why in some textbooks if im not mistaken i see them right the left limit and right limit when the variable approaches from negative or positive. thank you for your help.               p.s: small mistake you mean sin(y_n)

This technique that you mention, or even the one I presented in the answer above is useful for evaluating the non-existence of the limit, you can take particular sequences and verify that when evaluating the function it leads to different results.

ahh wonderful this was really helpful. thank you ever so much :)
